# redisc.RetryConn returns a null

Tags: go, redis-cluster, redigo

Golang and redis newbie. I have a redis cluster in amazon with 9 nodes. 3 master and for each master we have 2 slaves. Total nine nodes. Not using RetryConn returns a MOVED node error and using it returns a null. 
Is it important to give the IP address for all the nodes? IS it ok to give the host name that amz gives when we create the cluster.

```
cluster = redisc.Cluster{
         StartupNodes: []string{"*****"},
         DialOptions:  []redis.DialOption{redis.DialConnectTimeout(5 * 
time.Minute)},
         CreatePool: createPool,
         }
         if err := cluster.Refresh(); err != nil {
             log.Fatalf("Refresh failed: %v", err)
         }else{
             log.Println("Refresh worked")
         } 

func createPool(addr string, opts ...redis.DialOption) (*redis.Pool, 
error) {
return &redis.Pool{
    MaxIdle:     5,
    MaxActive:   10,
    IdleTimeout: time.Minute,
    Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
        c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "***", opts...)
        if err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }        

}, nil

}

func RedisConnection() redis.Conn {  
// grab a connection from the pool
conn := cluster.Get()
if(conn != nil){
    rc, err := redisc.RetryConn(conn, 9, 1*time.Second)
    if(err ==nil){
        return rc
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Also how do we binding the conn needed?Any insight would be very helpful

Comment: The logic around
 `
if(err !=nil){
        return rc
    }
` seems odd. (returning value only on error?). Also, should that parameter to `redis.Dial()` not be `addr`?

Comment: Typo while I was posting the question. func . What do mean the addr. Does it have to be  the IP ?
          RedisConnection() redis.Conn {  
        conn := cluster.Get()
               if(conn != nil){
                rc, err := redisc.RetryConn(conn, 9, 1*time.Second)
                if(err == nil){
                    return rc
                  }else{
                      spew.Dump(err)
                        return nil
                  }
          }else{
               log.Println("Conn is nil")
               return nil   
           }
    return nil
     }

Comment: When I use just addr in the redis.Dial("tcp",addr) I get the following error FAIL 0 ERR EXEC without MULTI